# iOS UITableView Cell Selection

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a custom cell called NewCell and I am trying to show a UIView called 'selectedView' within NewCell upon the click event.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NewCell *cell = (NewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.selectedView setHidden:NO];
}
```

EDIT - Adding cell creation code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NewCell";
    NewCell *productCell = (NewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (productCell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
        {
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                productCell = (NewCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    Product *mainProduct = [self.productsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    float floatPrice = [mainProduct.price floatValue];
    NSString *priceFormat;
    if ((int)floatPrice == floatPrice) priceFormat = @"$%.0f"; else priceFormat = @"$%.2f";

    produtCell.productPrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:priceFormat, floatPrice];

    return productCell;
}
```

Everything works fine and the table populates, but when I select a cell, it does not show selectedView on the cell that was selected in the table, but rather it shows selectedView in an opposite cell.
What I mean by this is, if row 0 and 1 are shown on the screen and I select row 1, it will show the selectedView on row 0 and if I select row 0, it will show selectedView on row 1.

Very strange, I can't seem to tell why it is doing this.

I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: This looks fine to me. Can you share your cell creation code?

Comment: darn, i figured it out.  I still actually had the productCell.selectionStyle set for the table. I removed that and now it works.  But with that in place, it makes it have an awkward side effect that I described in the OP

Comment: Glad you've figured it out. For future people, add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: thanks, but it says I have to wait 2 days to do that, maybe you can.  i just added it.

Answer (score 5):

The reason it is doing this is because you need to set your selection style to none like so:

```
productCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```